# Can we configure Oracle ADF Faces to produce valid XHTML?

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, xhtml

We are using [Oracle ADF Faces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Application_Development_Framework#History) in a new web project. I am always looking for an unobtrusive user experience with [progressive enhancement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and valid [XHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML) output. It seems however that ADF Faces produce ugly, non-validating (table based) HTML output that reminds me of 1994 when using their standard components.

Is there a way to configure ADF Faces or create templates for the components so we can have complete control over the generated (X)HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADF is a continuation of BC4J, so this is why you are experiencing non-validating HTML again. Instead, try to [write your own custom UI components](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/jdev/101/collateral/101/adffaces/howto_customcomponents.html).

Unfortunately, Stack Overflow does not bear much fruit in terms of Oracle help. Perhaps asking on Oracle OTN would help. Maybe raising an issue with meta-link too.

Answer (score -2):

You can not influence the ADF output HTML code. And rewitring all the [JSF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces) components is not an option. You can use [Google Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) which formats the HTML code for you.