# How to produce valid xhtml/xml output from Oracle ADF

Tags: doctype, oracle-adf, xhtml

I've tried to find a way to get our Oracle ADF pages to output valid code.
I see a reference in [Can we configure Oracle ADF Faces to produce valid XHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208295/can-we-configure-oracle-adf-faces-to-produce-valid-xhtml) but it's dated back in 2008 or so.
Is there still no way to configure ADF to output consistent code?

With no configuration we get a html 4.01 doctype but with a class attribute in the starting html element. For starters...
If we change the content type to application/xhtml+xml, as others suggest, we get the more correct xhtml 1.0 doctype.

BUT, the generated code is still html 4.0 :(
I.e. `<link href="cmp.css" type="text/css" charset="UTF-8" rel="stylesheet">`, without the closing tag.

So, has anyone actually solved this or is there only workarounds available?

Comment: What version? 11.1.2.3?

Comment: Oracle-Version: 11.1.1.6.38.61.92

Answer (score 0):

You may have a better chance nowadays using Alta UI, meaning you will get less validation errors than before, but a blunt answer is: NO, you won't be able to output valid XHTML from ADF.

ADF's wasn't geared towards a Light Effective HTML output at the beginning, but towards a Desktop-Like experience on web browser.
With Alta UI, things get slightly better.